# Can I use a DSN setting to retrieve multiple rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ado.net

I have re-posted this question using the correct terminology [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677860/odbc-has-setrowsetsize-what-is-the-equivalent-in-ado-net).

A customer is reporting a performance problem that appears to be linear with the number of rows returned from the query. That implies we are fetching one at a time.

Is there a way to tell the connection to retrieve multiple rows at a time using the connection string?

The code ultimately goes through SqlClientFactory. If there is no way to do it in the connection string, is there a way to do this in code?

I thought there would be lots of stuff on this, but either my Google-fu is failing me or I'm looking for the wrong thing.

Comment: In my experience, if your code is consuming data row-by-row, you'll need to redesign the code flow.  Changing a setting is unlikely to do what you want.

Comment: I have this nagging feeling in the back of my head that there is indeed a setting for this, that tells ADO how many rows to convert into the RecordSet at a time. Am I imagining this? I may be confusing it with EnterpriseObjects.

Comment: It depends on the type of construct used to read the data, which would require a code change and not a "setting" change.

Comment: Can you be more specific Sean? What do you mean by "type of construct"? I'm using a SqlClientFactory and RecordSets