# ODBC has SetRowsetSize, what is the equivalent in ADO.net?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I am looking for ways to deal with a high latency connection. ODBC has a `SetRowsetSize` that solves this problem, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/rowset-size) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92bcy0kw.aspx).

Is there an equivalent of this setting in ADO.net? [This article](http://sqlmag.com/business-intelligence/6-ways-boost-ado-application-performance) seems to suggest there is an analog in the original ADO, but it is very old and points to articles that no longer exist.

Generally speaking, how does one improve performance in ADO.net for high-latency connections?

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about latency while using ADO.NET with SQL Server, you should to look into [connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399543(v=vs.110).aspx). Though be mindful of [pool fragmentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Connecting to a data source can be time consuming. To minimize the
>   cost of opening connections, ADO.NET uses an optimization technique
>   called **connection pooling**, which minimizes the cost of repeatedly
>   opening and closing connections. Connection pooling is handled
>   differently for the .NET Framework data providers.

Additionally, if you need to retrieve many records rapidly, look into using the [SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx). It requires significantly less memory than a using other types of ADO.NET objects like DataSets and its optimized for efficiently fetching large amounts of data.

There are certain [performance counters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254503(v=vs.110).aspx) you can look at to see the number of active connection pools (**NumberOfActiveConnectionPools**) along with other useful information.

[Step by step guide on how to test](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/CMouli/monitoring-database-connections-using-performance-counters/).

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this is done automatically for every distinct connection string. We only have one connection, so don't all of my queries (which are all SELECTs BTW) go through the same connection pool by default? Is there any way to see the pool I'm in so I can test this?

Comment: You are correct. You asked a specific question about latency in regards to ADO.NET / SQL Server, hence answer discussing connection pooling. I've edited my answer with your question on how to test this.